# typescript multiple decimal point sort using rxjs replayobject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Below is my custom table component's sorting. It is working good for String and number data types except the multiple decimal point number.
**DTableSort.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: "myDefaultGSorter",
    template: `
        <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="sort()" class="text-nowrap" 
        [ngClass]="isSortedByMeAsc ? 'sort_by_asc' : isSortedByMeDesc ? 'sort_by_desc' : 'no_sorting'">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        </a>`
})
```

**DTable.ts**

```
import { Directive , EventEmitter , Input , Output , OnInit , OnChanges, DoCheck, IterableDiffers, IterableDiffer } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs";
import * as _ from "lodash";

export interface SortEvent {
  sortBy: string|string[];
  sortOrder: string
}

@Directive({
  selector: '<table [mxData]',
  exportAs: `mxDataTable`
})

export class DTableG implements OnChanges , OnInit, DoCheck  {

  private diff: IterableDiffer<any>;
  public onPageChange = new EventEmitter<PageEvent>();

  @Output() public onSortChange = new ReplaySubject<SortEvent>(1);
  @Input("mfSortBy") public sortBy: string|string[] = "";
  @Input("mfSortOrder") public sortOrder = "asc";
  @Input("mxData") public mxData : any[] = [];

  ngOnChanges() {        
    data = _.orderBy(data, this.sortBy, [this.sortOrder]);
  }
  /** sort */

  public setSort(sortBy: string|string[], sortOrder: string): void {
    if (this.sortBy !== sortBy || this.sortOrder !== sortOrder) {
        this.sortBy = sortBy;
        this.sortOrder = _.includes(["asc","desc"], sortOrder) ? sortOrder : "asc";
        this.onSortChange.next({sortBy: sortBy, sortOrder: sortOrder});  
        this.onSortChange.next({sortBy: sortBy, sortOrder: sortOrder});
     }
  }
}
```

And using the custom table and calling sort event with myDefaultGSorter  as below

```
<table class="dTable" [mxData]="mgmtList" style="width: 98%;margin: 0px auto;"
       #applListMgmtTable="mxDataTable" >
  <thead>

  <tr>
    <th style="width: 13%">
      <myDefaultGSorter by="requirementId">
        Requirement ID
      </myDefaultGSorter>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 32%">
      <myDefaultGSorter by="applicableRequirement">
        Applicable Requirement
      </myDefaultGSorter>
    </th>

    <th style="width: 15%">
      <myDefaultGSorter by="requirementSource">
        Source
      </myDefaultGSorter>
    </th>
    <th style="width: 8%">Action</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "let dataL of applListMgmtTable.data">
    <td>
      {{dataL.requirementId}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{dataL.applicableRequirement}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{dataL.requirementSource}}
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Requirement ids are getting sorted as

```
4.1.13
4.1.19
4.1.25
4.1.7
4.1.8
4.3.2
4.3.3
4.4.2
```

What I am expecting is as

```
4.1.7
4.1.8
4.1.13
4.1.19
4.1.25
4.3.2
4.3.3
4.4.2
```

Comment: can you add your sort function here which your are using to sort the data

Comment: @jitender added sort function in the question. It is in ngOnChanges()

Comment: may be this link can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080521/5621827

Comment: @jitender Yes i saw this link before posting this question. But i could not find how to use in my existing sort

Comment: It looks like `_.orderBy` accepts a string or a sort function for its second parameter. Try passing in a function that sorts the way you require.

Comment: @BizzyBob I tried with having the sort function from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080521/5621827 but it is not working. However i got some idea that we can have function in orderBy, thanks for that. Exploring more on that